# converting ; delimited CSV to tab delimited CSV

Tags: csv, vbscript

I want to convert `;`-delimited CSV to tab-delimited CSV. I have tried some options. I can convert it into tab delimited text file but I need tab delimited CSV file as the output. I need a VBScript code.

I have tried the following code which works but convert to tab delimited text file but I want tab delimited CSV file

```
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objFile : Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("\\vss22\Export\List\Export_File.csv")
Dim objOut : Set objOut = objFSO.CreateTextFile("\\vss22\Export\List\Export_File.txt")

arrData = objFile.ReadAll
objOut.Write Replace(Replace(arrData, ";",vbTab), chr(34), "")
objFile.Close
objOut.Close
```

---

**Edit:** Here is my Input file sample. I used the code as provided by @ansgar, but semicolon (`;`) is not replaced by tab.

```
PIM ID;Parent Product;Maintenance;MCH
 1;10001;10001;ABC
 2;20001;20001;ABC
 3;30001;30001;ABC
```

Output file is

```
PIM ID;Parent Product;Maintenance;MCH
 11000110001ABC
 22000120001ABC
 33000130001ABC
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
file = "\\vwq2702\HeilerExport\TaskList\Archive\List Values.csv"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

txt = fso.OpenTextFile(file).ReadAll
fso.OpenTextFile(file, 2).Write Replace(Replace(txt, ";", vbTab), Chr(34), "")
```

Comment: `...CreateTextFile(...Export_File.txt")`. Hmmm - why does this create a `.txt` instead of a `.csv`?

Comment: @Stephan Even if I change from Export_File.txt to Export_File.txt , it still creates a tab delimited text file

Comment: Please **show** the actual code you used to modify the file. It's unlikely that my code would remove some semicolons but leave others in place. Besides, I just tested my code with your sample data and the code does exactly what it's supposed to do. Also check the encoding of your input file.

Answer (score 2):

Just write the modified text back to the original file (after reading the file must be closed before you can open it for writing):

```
file = "\\vss22\Export\List\Export_File.csv"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

txt = fso.OpenTextFile(file).ReadAll
fso.OpenTextFile(file, 2).Write Replace(Replace(txt, ";", vbTab), Chr(34), "")
```

Comment: Sorry, It did not work. semi-colon (;) has been removed but data in all columns are just next to each other without any space/tab.

Comment: @adit I tested the code I posted and it works just fine. Please provide evidence.

Comment: I have provided the code, Input file sample and output result I am getting. Please take a look and let me know what I am missing.

Comment: @adit Did you check the encoding of the file? That's the only thing left I can think of. Please open it with a hex editor ([HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) for instance) and post the hex-representation of the first two lines from the input file.